# How to optimize postgresql procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have 61 million of non unique emails with statuses. 
This emails need to deduplicate with logic by status.

I write stored procedure, but this procedure runs to long.

How I can optimize execution time of this procedure?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.load_oxy_emails() RETURNS boolean AS $$

DECLARE
        row record;
        rec record;
        new_id int;
BEGIN
        FOR row IN SELECT * FROM oxy_email ORDER BY id LOOP
                SELECT * INTO rec FROM oxy_emails_clean WHERE email = row.email;
                IF rec IS NOT NULL THEN
                        IF row.status = 3 THEN
                                UPDATE oxy_emails_clean SET status = 3 WHERE id = rec.id;
                        END IF;
                ELSE
                        INSERT INTO oxy_emails_clean(id, email, status) VALUES(nextval('oxy_emails_clean_id_seq'), row.email, row.status);
                        SELECT currval('oxy_emails_clean_id_seq') INTO new_id;
                        INSERT INTO oxy_emails_clean_websites_relation(oxy_emails_clean_id, website_id) VALUES(new_id, row.website_id);
                END IF;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN true;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: `How I can optimize execution time of this procedure?`By **not** using a procedure with a cursor/loop. Instead, you can use two separate SQL statements (maybe glued together by a chained CTE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *How I can optimize execution time of this procedure?*

Don't do it with a loop.

Doing a row-by-row processing (also known as "slow-by-slow") is almost always a lot slower then doing bulk changes where a single statement processes a lot of rows "in one go".

The change of the status can easily be done using a single statement:

```
update oxy_emails_clean oec
    SET status = 3
from oxy_email oe
where oe.id = oec.id
  and oe.status = 3;
```

The copying of the rows can be done using a chain of [CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with to_copy as (
  select *
  from oxy_email 
  where status <> 3 --<< all those that have a different status
), clean_inserted as (
  INSERT INTO oxy_emails_clean (id, email, status) 
  select nextval('oxy_emails_clean_id_seq'), email, status
  from to_copy
  returning id;
) 
insert oxy_emails_clean_websites_relation (oxy_emails_clean_id, website_id)
select ci.id, tc.website_id
from clean_inserted ci
  join to_copy tc on tc.id = ci.id;
```